# webservice response time increased...how?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a webservice method:

```
[WebMethod]
public Response Process()
{
   return RunCode();
}
```

RunCode() takes 6 seconds to run but IIS/browser takes 20+ seconds to return the XML.

If I take RunCode() and put it in a thread, it now will return in 6 seconds:

```
private _response Response;
[WebMethod]
public Response Process()
{
   new Thread(RunProcess).Start()
   while(_response==null)
   {
     Thread.Sleep(100);
   }
   return _response;
}

private void RunProcess()
{
   _response=RunCode();
}
```

My question is this...what could be happening in RunCode() to force IIS/ASP.NET to delay the response? The code only takes 6 seconds to run...Is some sort of resource is getting tied up and locked if its not on a seperate thread, so ASP.NET waits for it?

Edit #1: an example of the response was requested.
An example of the response is this:

```
<PostResponse>
      <isValidPost>false</isValidPost>
      <ResponseType>Post_Over_Max</ResponseType>
      <ResponseDetails>System is currently at max leads allowed</ResponseDetails>
      <LeadIdentifier>0</LeadIdentifier>
      <VendorAccountAssigned>0</VendorAccountAssigned>
      <PendingQCReview>false</PendingQCReview>
      <Price>0</Price>
      <RedirectURL/>
</PostResponse>
```

based off of this class:

```
public class PostResponse : IPostResponse
{
    public PostResponse()
    {
    }

    public PostResponse(bool isValid, ResponseErrors responseType, string details, long leadIdentifier,
                        long vendorAccountAssigned, bool pendingQCReview, double price, string redirectUrl)
    {
        isValidPost = isValid;
        ResponseType = responseType;
        ResponseDetails = details;
        LeadIdentifier = leadIdentifier;
        VendorAccountAssigned = vendorAccountAssigned;
        PendingQCReview = pendingQCReview;
        Price = price;
        RedirectURL = redirectUrl;
    }

    #region IPostResponse Members

    public bool isValidPost { get; set; }
    public ResponseErrors ResponseType { get; set; }
    public string ResponseDetails { get; set; }
    public long LeadIdentifier { get; set; }
    public long VendorAccountAssigned { get; set; }
    public bool PendingQCReview { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string RedirectURL { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: How many times have you run the test after doing an IIS reset?

Comment: How much output is the method returning? Also, you don't need to do a "busy" while loop. You can do thread.Join() on the thread you created.

Comment: Your code could take 6 seconds to run, but how much work does IIS need to do to return the results to you, and accept the message from you?

Comment: -Maess: I've tried resetting IIS as well as completely removing and recreating the site from scratch with just the basics

Comment: – Ingenu: I've added an example response. Also, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: – Ryan Ternier: I don't understand your question... I guess that's where the problem lies, I'm not sure what IIS/ASP.NET is doing differently between threaded/not threaded with the response. I've edited and included an example, there's nothing crazy going on with the serialization of the response.

Comment: – Ryan Ternier: also, to expand on your thoughts...We have a copy of ANTS performance profiler to use, I can clearly see that the process method takes 6 seconds to run, there is no delay before-hand of the processing, only a delay after the processing while waiting for IIS to return the actual response.

Comment: Do you know at what point the extra 14 seconds is occurring?  In other words, how many seconds is elapsing prior to the request getting to the server, and how many occurs *after* your RunCode() method ends?  Also, is this an Ajax request?  If so, can you profile to javascript in the browser to see what it might be doing?

Comment: – Chris Lively: It all happens after the webservice method ends, nothing abnormal happens before. It is not an ajax call, a simple HTTP GET causes it as well as anything else (HTTP POST, XML POST).

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET runtime will will block threads from the same user session if a request is hanging.

[Why can’t I execute two requests from the same session simultaneously for an ASP.NET application?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitsh/archive/2007/08/01/why-i-cannot-execute-two-requests-from-the-same-session-simultaneously-for-an-asp-net-application.aspx)

Comment: The thing to note is that my entire webmethod only takes 6 seconds to run from start to finish, regardless of multiple concurrent requests...the delay happens AFTER my code runs when returning the response to the browser.

Comment: – x0n: the average POST takes about 500 ms, but this example does duplicate checking against realtime data across millions of rows, performs webservice calls, as well as all the normal things (database calls, etc). Trust me, its optimized...we used ANTS performance profiler to find bottlenecks to optimize the code. Where SQL would be too slow we've integrated mongo for flattened/cached data for quicker queries.